# Could you help me with a method that sums the areas of all rooms on the same floor?

Tags: java

I have two classes, the first is this:

```
public class Room {

public String typeOfRoom;
public double area;
public int floor;
public int windowsCount;

public String getTypeOfRoom() {
    return typeOfRoom;
}

public double getArea() {
    return area;
}

public int getFloor() {
    return floor;
}

public int getWindowsCount() {
    return windowsCount;
}

public void setTypeOfRoom(String typeOfRoom) {
    this.typeOfRoom = typeOfRoom;
}

public void setArea(double area) {
    this.area = area;
}

public void setFloor(int floor) {
    this.floor = floor;
}

public void setWindowsCount(int windowsCount) {
    this.windowsCount = windowsCount;
}

}
```

And the second is this:

```
public class House {

public Address addressOfHouse;
public Room bedroom;
public Room childrenroom;
public Room kitchen;
public Room livingroom;
public Room lobby;
public Room workroom;

public House (){
    addressOfHouse=new Address();
    bedroom=new Room();
    childrenroom=new Room();
    kitchen=new Room();
    livingroom=new Room();
    lobby=new Room();
    workroom=new Room();
}

public double totalArea (int floor){
    double totalArea=1;
    return totalArea;
}

public double totalArea (){
    //Here I do not know how to keep on...
}

}
```

My problem is that I have to complete the method "public double totalArea(){...}" and I am not sure about how to do it. This method should add all the areas of the rooms that are on the first floor of a house. I do not know exactly how to express it in the method, I do not know what kind of command I should use, I have thought of "if" or "for", but my biggest trouble is about how to express that the total area is the sum of the areas of the rooms on the first floor, if the area has to be set in the Main class and I do not know how to declare the "sum of the areas" in the method... Could you help me with that? If you could just give me some direction, just tell what steps I should follow, send links or something, I would be very glad. I have already looked for the solution of it for two weeks... I hope you have comprehended me. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hello, I would suggest adding a constructor to Room class that would allow you to specify the floor and the area of the room i.e. public Room(int floor, double area) link to read what is a constructor https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_constructors.htm .

Secondly in your not sure what is totalArea(int floor) is meant to do. For totalArea() as you said you are trying to calculcate area of all rooms in floor. So you could check room floor i.e. beedroom.getFloor() == 1 link about if statement  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/if_statement_in_java.htm and adding rooms area to a counter

Comment: Can you work out how to do it with pen and paper? If so, do that and then try writing the code. Side note: your `totalArea (int floor)` is pointless as it just returns `1` every time.

Comment: Thank you, @DonatasD, for the answer (suggestions and links), it was indeed useful! Thank you for the suggestion, @achAmháin! I suspected that I had made some mistake in the method "totalArea (int floor)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `ArrayList` to save all the `Room` objects in the `House` class and iterate through the list and sum the areas:

```
public class House {

    public Address addressOfHouse;
    public Room bedroom;
    public Room childrenroom;
    public Room kitchen;
    public Room livingroom;
    public Room lobby;
    public Room workroom;
    private ArrayList<Room> rooms;

    public House (){
        addressOfHouse=new Address();

        rooms = new ArrayList<>();

        bedroom=new Room();
        rooms.add(bedroom);
        childrenroom=new Room();
        rooms.add(childrenroom);
        kitchen=new Room();
        rooms.add(kitchen);
        livingroom=new Room();
        rooms.add(livingroom);
        lobby=new Room();
        rooms.add(lobby);
        workroom=new Room();
        rooms.add(workroom);
    }

    public double totalArea (int floor){
        double totalArea=0.0;

        for (Room room : rooms) {
            if (room.getFloor() == floor)
                totalArea += room.getArea();
        }

        return totalArea;
    }

    public double totalArea (){
        return totalArea(1);
    }

}
```

The `totalArea(int floor)` method returns the area of `i` floor.  
So if you want the `totalArea()` method to return the 1st floor's area, you must return `totalArea(1)`. 
Maybe you should change the name of `totalArea()` to `totalAreaofFirstFloor()`?  
 All the `Room` objects in `House` class need initialization with valid values for their properties.

Comment: In that case I'd recommend getting rid completely of the `Room` fields, as they are now refered twice in a `House` instance. In addition a single `ArrayList` will allow for more flexibility on the number of rooms you can put in your house.

Comment: @forpas, I accepted your answer, then I thought that I could accept another together with yours, but now I am seeing that I can do it with only one. Yours is accepted again. Thank you! By the way, I would like to know if I may make another question here:

At this part of the code: "for (Room room : rooms) {
            if (room.getFloor() == floor)
                totalArea += room.getArea();" What should I replace? The "floor" after "==" by "1"? Only that? I guess I do not have to mention that I am a total beginner at Java, so I am just sorry for that...

Comment: @DosS Nothing to replace. This method can return the area of any floor. You can use it like I did in the other `totalArea()` (which you should rename to `totalAreaofFirstFloor()`) like `totalArea(1)` or `totalArea(2)` to get the area of any floor.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need a Room constructor that accepts parameters (right now you are using the default constructor, so every variable is set to 0/null)

```
public Room(String typeOfRoom /* ... other params */){ 
   this.typeOfRoom = typeOfRoom;
   //assign other params
}
```

Then you will need to write the method:

```
 public double totalArea (int floor){
    double totalArea=0.0;

    //check if bedroom is on this floor:
    if(bedroom.getFloor() == floor) {
       totalArea += bedroom.getArea();
    }
    //now do this for all other rooms

    return totalArea;
}
```

May be more elegant to colect the rooms in something and iterate through that, but this will do as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Gtomika, it has helped me much!

Comment: You are welcome. If my answer solved the problem, please mark it as accepted, so other users may notice it faster!

Answer (score 1):

For computing the overall area for all the floors of all rooms, you can write a method like this,

```
public double totalArea() {
    double totalArea = 0;
    totalArea += bedroom.getArea();
    totalArea += childrenroom.getArea();
    totalArea += kitchen.getArea();
    totalArea += livingroom.getArea();
    totalArea += lobby.getArea();
    totalArea += workroom.getArea();

    return totalArea;
}
```

But you should create a proper constructor of Room class, so one can properly create Room object and can specify the parameters into it. Room constructor can be something like this,

```
public Room(String typeOfRoom, double area, int floor, int windowsCount) {
    this.typeOfRoom = typeOfRoom;
    this.area = area;
    this.floor = floor;
    this.windowsCount = windowsCount;
}
```

Also, you should create a better constructor of House object, where it can take room objects of various types of room. Your house constructor can be something like this,

```
public House(Address addressOfHouse, Room bedroom, Room childrenroom, Room kitchen, Room livingroom, Room lobby, Room workroom) {
    this.addressOfHouse = addressOfHouse;
    this.bedroom = bedroom;
    this.childrenroom = childrenroom;
    this.kitchen = kitchen;
    this.livingroom = livingroom;
    this.lobby = lobby;
    this.workroom = workroom;
}
```

You also need to improve your method for calculating area for a particular floor to something like this,

```
public double totalArea(int floor) {
    double totalArea = 0;
    totalArea += bedroom.getFloor() == floor ? bedroom.getArea() : 0;
    totalArea += childrenroom.getFloor() == floor ? childrenroom.getArea() : 0;
    totalArea += kitchen.getFloor() == floor ? kitchen.getArea() : 0;
    totalArea += livingroom.getFloor() == floor ? livingroom.getArea() : 0;
    totalArea += lobby.getFloor() == floor ? lobby.getArea() : 0;
    totalArea += workroom.getFloor() == floor ? workroom.getArea() : 0;

    return totalArea;
}
```

And then finally you can write some code in main method to test how it works,

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Room bedroom = new Room("bedroom", 200, 1, 4);
    Room childrenroom = new Room("childrenroom", 180, 1, 2);
    Room kitchen = new Room("kitchen", 160, 2, 2);
    Room livingroom = new Room("livingroom", 220, 2, 2);
    Room lobby = new Room("lobby", 140, 2, 4);
    Room workroom = new Room("workroom", 100, 2, 2);
    Address address = new Address();

    House house = new House(address, bedroom, childrenroom, kitchen, livingroom, lobby, workroom);

    // total area of all rooms
    System.out.println("Total area: " + house.totalArea());

    // total area of all rooms on floor 1
    System.out.println("Total area on floor 1: " + house.totalArea(1));

    // total area of all rooms on floor 2
    System.out.println("Total area on floor 2: " + house.totalArea(2));
}
```

This prints following output like expected,

```
Total area: 1000.0
Total area on floor 1: 380.0
Total area on floor 2: 620.0
```

Hope this helps and let me know if you still have any queries further.